# Restarting firebase queue when node process has crashed

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-queue

I'm using firebase-queue for running some simple tasks. Suppose a task has been picked up by a worker and its state has been updated as in_progress. Now node crashes and the worker exists no more. The next time I restart node, how can I make sure that the tasks that were earlier in_progress gets picked up by firebase-queue after the restart? I'm using specs where I have defined the `error_state`, `start_state`, `finished_state`, `in_progress_state` and `retries`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. I was just setting the `retries` property. `timeout` should also be set manually. Setting `timeout` did the job for me